# Vaadin 8 Download option is not working in Chrome 76

Tags: google-chrome, amazon-ec2, download, vaadin, vaadin8

We are using vaadin 8 and using iframes for download csv option. Whenever i try to download i get below error. However it is working fine on local system. We are using spring boot for this application. and AWS for dev and qa server.

Kindly suggest the solution.

[Intervention] Download in ad frame without user activation is not allowed. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/6311883621531648 for more details.

Below are the code snippet which we are using of Vaadin library

```
 fileDownloader = new FileDownloader(streamResource) {
             @Override
             public boolean isOverrideContentType() {
                 return false;
             }
         };
         fileDownloader.extend(this); 

 public void download(ClickEvent clickEvent) {
        executeDownload();
    }

    private void executeDownload() {
        if (getParent() == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("OnclickDownloadComponent has to be attached to a UI in order to work properly. " +
                    "It is set to display=none to make it invisible but it has to be rendered on the page.");
        }
        Page.getCurrent().getJavaScript().execute("document.getElementById('" + styleId + "').click();");
    }
```

Comment: Please show your code for the download

Comment: @AndréSchild code snippet updated.

Comment: This code snippet doesn't help much, as we don't know where `OnclickDownloadComponent` (in iframe? in the same layout?) is located and from where the `download` is called. If I am simply calling `Page.getCurrent().getJavaScript()....` from a button event click to cause another button click, then file is downloaded. We would need to have a complete example :)

Comment: Does it work if you use the official vaadin 8 download component?

Comment: Hi guys we are using button and FileDownloader for the same.                                                                                                 
       fileDownloader = new FileDownloader(streamResource) {
             @Override
             public boolean isOverrideContentType() {
                 return false;
             }
         };
         fileDownloader.extend(this);